# C# WinForms - Detect User Click Into Text Box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been developing a windows form application and ran into a problem.

After trying various things (Listed below) I have come to seek your knowledge to help point me in the right direction.

I have replicated a much simpler version of my program:

[image]

As you can see, I have two textboxes. I want to be able to click on the textbox on the bottom (textbox1) and call some form of an event, in this case, for simplicity, pop up a message box.

I have been through the events listed here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx
And implemented them into my code as I expected one of them to work. However, this is not the case.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TextBox Entered");
    }
    //Above - Will pop message box when text entered.
    private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TextBox Entered");
    }

    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TextBox Entered");
    }

    private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TextBox Entered");
    }
```

Does anybody know what I am missing? I presume what I am trying to achieve is actually possible?

Kind Regards,
B.

Comment: Is you text box subscribed to the events? Click on the text box in the Design view and check the events are listed in the events tab (looks like a lightning bolt).

Comment: Ah, excellent! I have never encountered this before. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Next time, double click that area in the events window and it will both generate the event body for you, and subscribe to it automatically.

Comment: Ah okay thank you for that tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the event is subscribed to the methods you have written. You can do this in the design view using the Events tab of the property window (looks like a lightning bolt). As mentioned by others, a double click in the events window will generate the event's method for you, and subscribe to it automatically.

Another way is to subscribe directly using code; you could write this in the form constructor for example:

```
textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
```